GitHub Flow and conflicting PRs when testing in PR environment
I really like the idea of GitHub Flow and would like to give it a shot.
The way we want to do testing and setup is to create a separate environment on each PR using terraform and containers. When automated, manual tests are completed there code would be merged to main branch and deployed to alpha and later production environment.
The only thing that I'm not sure of is how to keep those environments up to date when multiple developers work in parallel.
Example:

developer 1 rebranches from main. He creates a PR locally, develops a feature 1, publishes the PR and new testing environment is created. There additional E2E and manual tests are run. Code gets merged back to main when all is green
developer 2 does exactly same steps in parallel. If feature 1 of developer 1 gets merged first this means he no longer works on the latest version of code. E2E and manual tests done here are in theory being done on main branch minus feature 1.

Is the solution here to have automation somehow checking if developer 2 in fact runs the test on latest version of code before he is allowed to merge? Recreating an environment is a slow process so doing so each time new code is pushed and rerunning the tests doesn't seem all that great.
I would assume these types of scenarios where there will be issues of this kind are rare. However I see how they can occur. With standard GitFlow we test a release branch with final round of tests. So at least we know nothing knew will suddenly appear unexpectedly.
